# What is the meaning of this error? ( java.io.IOException No active nodes contain this block )

Tags: hdfs, webhdfs

```
{
    ""
    RemoteException "": {
        ""
        exception "": ""
        IOException "",
        ""
        javaClassName "": ""
        java.io.IOException "",
        message "": ""
        No active nodes contain this block ""
    }
}
```

What is the meaning of this error? Although I'm not sure, I think I received this error while reading the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your Datanode is started before Namenode And when Namenode started it could not found your Datanode, as it is not registered to the Namenode. This is why it cant find the bloack on that node.
You can go through the script start-all.sh and check if Namenode starts before the Datanodes.